# How to set a default (or base) rotation on a transformer in KonvaJS?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

#### Some context:

In my application, I have to display generated SVGs, which causes no issues.

But at some point, the back-end may (and will) return a rotated (modified) SVG, that I display in the canvas (I do know the actual rotation).

### My issue:

My issue is that I cannot find a way to set the transformer base rotation.

For example, I know the image I inserted is a 90° rotated image, and I would like to have this rotation shown through the transformer when the image is selected (image has a base "canvas-rotation" of 0°, and the transformer a base "canvas-rotation" of 90°).

#### Summary:

To put it in another way, is it possible to offset the transformer rotation based on the attached node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set "rotation offset" for `Konva.Transformer`. You have to use node's rotation for that. If you have an SVG image you can draw it into the offscreen canvas with rotation, and then use that canvas for `Konva.Image`.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, 0);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width * Math.cos(Math.PI / 4), canvas.height * Math.cos(Math.PI / 4))

  var yoda = new Konva.Image({
    x: 60,
    y: 60,
    image: canvas,
    draggable: true
  });
  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(yoda);


  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    node: yoda
  })
  layer.add(tr);
  layer.draw();
};
imageObj.src = 'https://konvajs.org/assets/yoda.jpg';
```

https://jsbin.com/korigegupo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: For my application, the canvas may have thousands of images (with dozen or hundreds of unique images). Won't creating so many canvas hinder the performances ?

Comment: It will. But are you sure you need all of them at the same time? Only create a canvas when it is visible.

Comment: Sadly yes, I need to be able to display all the images on screen. I think I will manage something out anyway since there will only be 4 possible rotations for each images, so I can keep a "registry" of the images and then simply clone to limit the number of unique canvas. I accept your answer since it solves the problem I described in my question. Thank you for taking the time to answer !